# How to resolve a collection of interfaces with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have a class with a constructor which takes a collection of child interfaces

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
   public Manager(IEnumerable<IDataAccess> dataAccess)
   {
```

IDataAccess is a base interface

```
public interface IFooDataAccess : IDataAccess
{

public interface IBarDataAccess : IDataAccess
{

public interface IBazDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
```

There are concrete implementations for each of these.
When I resolve IManager I want the dataAccess parameter to be populated with a collection of FooDataAccess, BarDataAccess and BazDataAccess.

I'm using unity as an IoC, the current registration is:

```
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(
                typeof(IManager).Assembly),
            WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
            WithName.Default,
            WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

I do have a few other classes in the solution too (hence using a registration pattern) so I'd like to keep this. I've been playing around with trying to register IManager on it's own:

```
        var allDataAccesses = container.ResolveAll<IDataAccess>();
        var parameter = new InjectionConstructor(allDataAccesses);
        container.RegisterType<IManager, Manager>(parameter);
```

But I can't get it to work, what am I missing. How can I configure unity to resolve the constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The registrations that you did will map the directly implemented interfaces and not `IDataAccess`.

For example, it will map `IFooDataAccess` to `FooDataAccess`. What you need is to map `IDataAccess` to `FooDataAccess` for example.

To solve this, add the following registration code:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    typeof (IManager)
        .Assembly
        .GetTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsClass)
        .Where(x => typeof (IDataAccess).IsAssignableFrom(x)),
    x => new[] {typeof (IDataAccess)},
    WithName.TypeName, WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

This will search the assembly for classes that implement `IDataAccess` (directly or indirectly), and will create a map between `IDataAccess` and these classes.

One important thing to note here is that it gives the registration a name. This is important because if you have the interface `IDataAccess` mapped to many classes, then you cannot use the default name. How would unity know which map entry to use?

Another thing you need to do is to map `IEnumerable<IDataAccess>` to `IDataAccess[]` like this:

```
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IDataAccess>, IDataAccess[]>();
```

Unity knows how to resolve arrays by looking at named registrations for the required interface. It cannot by default do the same for `IEnumerable<T>`. An alternative for this is to change the constructor to use an array like this:

```
public class Manager : IManager
{
    public Manager(IDataAccess[] dataAccess)
    {
        ....
    }

    ....
}
```